# How can I change "main" file setting for mocha in package.json while invoking mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am working on a nodejs project and implementing unit tests for the existing modules. It is a rest api and we don't have a single main file (index.js), instead we have several files which service based on the request URL. Is there a way to define "main" option dynamically while invoking mocha in package.json? I am new to nodejs so if it's not the right question correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass arguments to any npm script in your package.json by invoking `--` after the call. In that way, for the following script in package.json configuration,

```
scripts: {
    test: "mocha"
}
```

You can pass the desired file/folder by calling `npm test -- <path to file you want to test>`

By default, just by running `mocha` ( if you have installed it globally in your environment ) or `npm test`, giving the previous script configuration, it will run all tests found in `./test`, but not its children folders.